# Auto layout issue with a row of image views

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

This is driving me nuts!

I am trying to show a row of images of followers to a profile in my app. The idea is for it to be 5 images where you could theoretically click on them and move to their profile.

Here is what I am having troubles with now :

[image: Autolayout hell]

I've never had to ask about auto layout before so I don't know what to show you all for your help. Is feel like this is a silly problem...

Here is the setup:

- Designed in a separate XIB
- All elements are encapsulated in a UITableViewCell

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: So as per Michal I tried a stack view and although it seemed like the right thing to do it honestly gave me the same results, so I am sure I am doing this wrong. Please see images below**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you plan to support iOS 9 only? If so, `UIStackView` would probably be the simplest solution.

Comment: I attempted a UICollectionView, is a StackView similar? The issue I was having was that I have this as a separate XIB and a custom table view cell, so I am not sure how to pass delegates over the underlying view controller that simply registers to this nib.

Comment: @MichałCiuba So I tried the stack view and my results are above please see original post.

Comment: Select all of your UIImageView's and set them to have equal widths (Shift+click all UIImageView's... click add new constraints icon on bottom right in Interface Builder... Select 'Equal Widths' then Add Constraints

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog If I do that then all the images get stretched, which could be because of my constraints....

Comment: No that makes sense that would happen, but your getting closer.  Apply the aspect ratio constraint to each of your UIImageView's

Comment: adding Equal Widths will work if you have enough images to fill the row, if your images are 1:1 ratio, and sometimes you may want to show less 'Followers'. I think the best option is a UICollectionview and set the width of the cells to be equal to the container.

Comment: @OscarJ.Irun I initially thought that same thing, but I have no clue how to make a collection view work in a custom NIB + Custom uitableviewcell... it tried and almost snapped my laptop in half. But you are correct, i will need to not have a fixed amount, cause different width phones...

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog I tried both things and it is looking better, still not right, its as thought they are "larger" also my console gets flooded with Autolayout complaints...

Comment: Good almost there, now add a height constraint to each UIImageView so that their height will remain constant.. Then select each UIImageView and set the equal height constraint just like you did with width... I am assuming you have already set each UIImageView's leading and trailing space constraints... If not then set the leading and trailing constraints individually for each UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured I would make this an answer so that the comments don't get too long. So, with everything these are the constraints you should have added:

1) Set all UIImageView's to have equal widths

2) Set all UIImageView's aspect ratio constraint

3) Add a height constraint to each UIImageView

4) Set all UIImageView's to have equal heights, just like with width in step 1

5) Set leading and trailing space constraints for each UIImageView. This one is a little tricky.  The first UIImageView should have a leading constraint = x.  The last UIImageView should have a trailing constraint = x.  The constraints between each UIImageView should be >= x.

This is the icon for selecting constraints:

[image]

Comment: Yeah thanks for that! I am trying to get all that you said working. But now I am worried about how this will behave on a smaller screen, should it still work?

Comment: Yes this will work on any screen size.  It will keep your UIImageView's the same aspect ratio, have varying widths between each UIImageView, and leave the height of the UIImageView's the same no matter screen width.  So for example, if the screen width was 1 foot wide then everything would stay the same, but the space between each UIImageView would change according to screen width... and the left and right UIImageView's would be pinned to the sides.

Comment: Okay thats perfect exactly what I am looking for. When you say the constraints between image views, should I just use the horizontal spacing constraint that Xcode provides?

Comment: When you click on the UIImageView, then the bottom right icon, you can select Leading and Trailing space constraints.  I added a picture to the answer so you see what I mean.

Comment: Haha yeah I just realized that's what it was, now the way I have my cell setup the first and last image need to be at the edge of each's respective side. I for the first image view I want to create a leading = superview?

Comment: Yes, and the trailing should be >= the next UIImageView ....... and for the last UIImageView you want the trailing = superview and the leading >= the closest UIImageView.... also make sure Constrain to margins is not checked

Comment: Nvm the last comment, so what I have is 0,8 for first and 8,8 for the middle 3 and then 8,0 for the last one.

Comment: Okay great, it seems that I got the images working nicely, but now it's complaining about the other views as they are now confused... I will keep playing with it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103651/discussion-between-andy-and-msu-bulldog).