# Autolayout - Unable to satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

**Update: So I tried adding a stack view and noticed an interesting phenomenon. It seems that when I have the last image view or the edge of the stack view have a trailing edge to superview = -1 (Xcode default) it stretches everything and breaks the images. But if I don't have that constraint it doesn't spread them equally on the cell but all the images fit properly... How do I achieve the combination of the two!!!**

Okay all just to preface this, here is the original question that started all of this : [Auto layout issue with a row of image views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442912/auto-layout-issue-with-a-row-of-image-views)

I went with the accepted answer and was able to achieve an almost right looking answer :

[image]

The issue now being that it's breaking constrains for some reason and the images are not perfectly circular anymore.

I get what looks like 5 sets of warnings of broken constraints. From what I can tell it's breaking the width of 55 for each image view.

I am new to auto layout and am totally confused with why this would be happening. I will paste the output below, if you need any more info please let me know.

**First**

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5470 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5570 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5640 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5750 UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f57a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5860 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f58b0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5970 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f59c0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f60e0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6130 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6300 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6460 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6630 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6740 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.trailing - 1>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c130dd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0(375)]>"


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5970 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860(55)]>
```

**Second**

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5470 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5570 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5640 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5750 UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f57a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5860 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f58b0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f60e0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6130 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6300 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6460 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6630 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6740 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.trailing - 1>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6570 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c130dd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0(375)]>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5860 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20(55)]>
```

**Third**

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5470 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5570 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5640 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5750 UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f57a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f60e0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6130 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6300 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6460 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6570 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6630 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6740 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.trailing - 1>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6790 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c130dd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0(375)]>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f57a0 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00(55)]>
```

**Fourth**

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5470 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5570 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5640 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f60e0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6130 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6300 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6460 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6570 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6630 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6740 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.trailing - 1>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6790 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6350 UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c130dd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0(375)]>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5570 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60(55)]>
```

**Fifth**

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030(55)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5470 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f60e0 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6130 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6300 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6350 UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6460 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc29deea00]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6570 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6630 H:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0d7860]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6740 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0.trailingMargin == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.trailing - 1>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6790 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c0e7b20.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f6240 UIImageView:0x7ffc2c094a60.width == UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c130dd0 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffc2c08ccc0(375)]>"

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffc2c0f5420 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffc2c035030(55)]>
```

From what I can tell it looks like the image views are not happy with how they are being aligned with the button below and the label above.

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-constraining your views.

You have a constraint telling your image views to have 55 height and a 1.0 aspect ratio, so they also have 55 width. 5 * 55 for the images plus 4 * 8 for the spacing between gives a total width of 315 for your view, but the screen isn't 315 wide so the system has to break some of your constraints (it is choosing to break the 55 height one in this case).

You need to either remove the 55 height constraint so the image views can grow in size depending on how wide they have to be to fill the screen or change your spacing constraints so that they can increase the spacing in between your image views to fill the screen while keeping the same dimensions.

Comment: The dimension are important cause they will be pictures so they can be wider or longer on one side, but you were saying something about making the spacing constraint expand. How would you do that? If I add this to a stack view I have to manually give it a fixed constant for spacing, which I chose 8pts.

Comment: I would definitely use a stack view if you are only supporting iOS 9+.  I've never used a stack view so I don't personally know how to do it though.  Doing it without a stack view would require putting in a bunch of spacer views which is a pain.

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense, a stack view seems to be the way to go... still doesn't really work the way I am imaging. Can you come up with another way of showing this info (I thought of UICollectionView, but I don't know how to embed one in a custom uitableview cell...)

Comment: It should definitely be possible to get what you want using a stack view.  Have you tried setting the distribution to EqualSpacing or EqualCentering?  Those let you set a minimum spacing and have it grow if the view has extra space which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I tried EqualSpacing, but I don't see what you are talking about, I see a section where I can add a spacing constant...

Comment: Nvm I was missing a constraint and with equal spacing it work! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out...

A stack view with equal spacing, and a leading space to margin makes it so the spacing constraint changes as necessary with different widths. Adding simple aspect ratios and a Height to each image view makes it work.

Comment: Hahaha, same issue with "fill proportionally". Thanks!